# UiPath - slow opening Word & Excel

Tags: uipath

I'm working with Word & Excel within UiPath.

But opening these applications takes approximately 20 seconds ?

I created a test XAML file with just 2 activities

1. Open App
2. Message box

Properties for Open App
File Name : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE"
Selector :

It takes about 20 seconds ... no error message ... just a 20 second wait ?!?!

I have tested opening Word using the Windows Run command ... it opens immediately !

Comment: What is the selector property?
Does it take around 20 seconds to open or it opens instantly but it takes ~20 seconds to proceed to the next activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is the value of your Selector property but I think it's because of it. Open Application does two steps: first it opens the application, second it will search for the selector to create a Target Element for further use. The timeout for finding an element is 30 seconds by default, thus the slow response.

If you do not need the scope activity you can simply use Start Process activity.
If you are not sure what the selector should be you can set up a general one:

```
<wnd app='excel.exe' />
```